# SQL - Select unique row with average of all other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am struggling with a SQL query that I initially thought should be quite simple.

Imagine a table `Users` that uses a `UserID` as the PK and a column `Age` for the users age:

```
    UserID     Age
    1          22
    2          34
    3          23
    4          19
    etc.
```

I'd like to be able to specify a UserID and return that user's age as well as the average age of all other users. For example, if I specify UserID 1 then I'd like to see return set as:

```
   UserID      Age      AvgAge
   1           22       24.5
```

The following does not work: (as the `WHERE` is performed before `GROUP BY`)

```
  Select UserID, Age, Avg(Age) as 'AvgAge'
  From Users
  Where UserID = 1
  Group By UserId, Age

  UserID      Age      AvgAge    //Result set
  1           22       22
```

Can anybody nudge me in the right direction?

By the way, in an ideal world the average age should *not* include the user that has been specified as the idea is to show their age relative to the average age of everybody else.

Given that there are 1000+ users then taking an average over all users will make no practical difference to the `AvgAge` number, though if anybody would like to show off their SQL prowess with a solution to that then I'd be interested to see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @T table
(
  UserID int,
  Age int
)

insert into @T values
    (1,          22),
    (2,          34),
    (3,          23),
    (4,          19)

declare @UserID int = 1

select Age, (select avg(Age*1.0)
             from @T
             where UserID <> @UserID) as AvgAge
from @T
where UserID = @UserID
```

Result:

```
Age         AvgAge
----------- ---------------------------------------
22          25.333333
```

Comment: I assume the `*1.0` is to ensure that `AVG` produces a float rather than an integer?

Comment: @Remnant - Yep. Otherwise you would have got `25` assuming that `Age` is and `int`.

Comment: @Remnant - Actually it is not a `float` but a `numeric(38,6)` in this case.

Comment: I have been using `CAST(Age As Float)` but your method seems like a really neat away of achieving the same result. Hadn't thought about that before. Good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

This query excludes the user with the specified id from the average, as requested. You used MAX in your example, which is not going to give you the average, but if MAX is actually what you want, you can just swap it with AVG in this query and it'll work.

```
 SELECT u.UserID, 
        u.Age,
        (SELECT AVG(uavg.Age)
           FROM Users uavg
          WHERE uavg.UserID != u.UserID) AS AvgAge
    FROM Users u
   WHERE u.UserID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. `+1`. I will go with Mikael answer as his query returns a float whereas your query returns an integer `26` but just as good really. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. MySQL returns a float, so that's a nice little bit of SQL-Server trickery I've learnt today :)

Answer (score 1):

use what you need `avg` for average and `max` for maximum age:

```
Select 
 UserID, 
 Age, 
 (select Max(Age) from Users) as 'AvgAge'
  From Users
  Where UserID = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    u.UserId, 
    u.Age, 
    b.AvgAge 
FROM 
    dbo.Users a, 
    (SELECT AVG(Age*1e0) as AvgAge FROM dbo.Users) as b
```

Comment: There is no `WHERE` clause to specify the user?

Comment: The result will be the table of users with the average age (actually always the same number per query) so if you want to add WHERE clause, it's a basic SQL knowledge
    WHERE u.UserId = <NUMBER>

Comment: Thanks much. +1. My comment about the `WHERE` was written in a light hearted manner!

Answer (score 1):

```
  Select U.UserID, u.Age, sq.Age as 'AvgAge'
      From Users u
      join (select average(age) as Age from users) sq on 1=1
      Where UserID = 1
      Group By UserId, Age
```

Comment: Simply a condition to force the join to match every record (in this case, only one record)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @T table (UserID int, Age int)  
insert into @T values(1,22),(2,34),(3,23),(4,19)  

declare @UserID int = 1 

;with a as
(
  select userid, Age, 
  avg(age * case when userid <> @userid then 1.0 end) over() 'AvgAge'
from @T             
)
select Age, AvgAge from a
where userid = @UserID
```